# How to efficiently use multiple CKEditor5 instances on a page?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ckeditor

I have a form with potentially 200+ inputs. It is required to use CKEditor5 for all inputs. However, if I load all 200 CKEditor5's at the same time, the page takes more than 10 seconds to open. The current implementation is as follows.

Template:

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let question of questionList; let i = index">
        <!-- Other views here -->

        <ckeditor [editor]="editor" [(ngModel)]="question.prompt"></ckeditor>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Component:

```
import * as InlineEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline';
// Other imports

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questions',
  templateUrl: './questions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questions.component.scss']
})
export class QuestionsComponent {
  @Input() questionList: QuestionModel[];
  editor = InlineEditor;

  // Other code
}
```

How can I use CKEditor for all inputs without freezing the page or accordion animations? I tried a few things but none of them worked.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672506/7279624) proposes a solution but I don't know how to implement it.

> Initialize the editor only after clicking on an editable element.
> Destroy old editor on blur event or clicking on the second editable
> element and initialize new one on the given text - it would require
> creating a simple wrapper over the element